# Change selected dropdown depending on category from item from DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

So i have some items in my `DB`, that has a category like example: New, Old, To-Old etc.

I also have a `dropdown` where you can change the category of them, but as i want to edit the item, i want the `dropdown` to show the current category. But as it is for now, it's showing the first(Alle) category in the `dropdown` cause it's in the top.

How can i get the dropdown the show the right category?

I pull the category out in `PHP` like this:

```
<? echo $row['abo_type']?>
```

**HTML: my categorys**

```html
<select id="filter_type">
                    <option value="Alle">Alle</option>
                    <option value="Privat_Tale">Privat Tale</option>
                    <option value="Erhverv_Tale">Erhverv Tale</option>
                    <option value="Gamle">Gamle Tale</option>
                    <option value="Privat_MBB">Privat MBB</option>
                    <option value="Erhverv_MBB">Erhverv MBB</option>
                    <option value="Retention">Retention</option>
     <option value="Gamle_Privat_MBB">Erhverv MBB</option>
     <option value="Gamle_Erhverv_MBB">Erhverv MBB</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Only with your html, its hard to understand what you do in your server side

Comment: `<?php echo $row['abo_type']?>` or `<?= $row['abo_type']?>`

Comment: Can you show some php code as well?

Comment: Well thats the problem. I have no php code for the category, except some when i insert it into the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an option selected in the drop down list use can add selected attribute to that option, like this

```
<select id='filter-type'>
<option value ='xyz' <?php echo ( $row['abo_type']==='xyz')?"selected":""?> >XYZ</option>
<option value ='abc' <?php echo ( $row['abo_type']==='abc')?"selected":""?> >ABC</option>
```

Or use the javascript on page load

```
var selected_category = '<?php echo $row['abo_type'];?>';
$("#filter-type").val(selected_category);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first above solution did what i needed to. Thanks